# Multilingual Title Page with Babel?

Tags: titles, babel

I normally use `xelatex`, but I prefer the look of documents printed with `pdflatex`. That said, I am more familiar with `\polyglossia` than `\babel`. Also, I keep LaTeX templates around to make it easier to do things in the future.

That all said, today is a slow day and I figured that I would typeset some online Articles in Russian for fun, for personal use, and take the opportunity to *kern* a few templates for typesetting documents in Russian, for when I need them in the future.

The issue, I am running into is how I spell my name. My name is legally, “Matthew,” but I spell it on everything except legal documents as, “Matþew.” So the issue I am being given is that, `{\th}` is not in the `T2A` font encoding schema. I am, however, calling, of course, both `T1` and `T2A`. I figured, it was an issue of needing to declare English being used in the author section, but I am having trouble finding out how to do that.

This is my Preamble:

```
% pdflatex

\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

    % ===MAIN PACKAGES===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

        \usepackage[USenglish,main=russian]{babel}

            \addto\captionsUSenglish{%
                \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
                {Table of Contents}%
            }

        \usepackage{indentfirst}

%%%     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % DEPROCATED IN NEWEST VERSIONS       %

%%%     \usepackage[pass]{geometry} % ALLOWS DECLARATION OF PAPER SIZE... %
                                    % IN SOME INSTANCES, WHERE NEEDED     %


    % ===SECONDARY PACKAGES===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \usepackage{xcolor}     % HIGHLIGHTING COLOURS

        \usepackage{soul}       % HIGHLIGHTING AND BETTER UNDERLINING 


    % ===TITLE===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \title{%
            Учимся говорить по-алтайски.    \\%
            %
            Урок № 1. Алфавит.%
        }


        \author{%
            ~Typeset by:    \\%
            %
            Mat{\th}ew T. Scarbrough%
        }

        \date{\today}
```

I doubt the body is important, but here is that:

```
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman} % ===FRONTMATTER===


    % ===TITLE===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \maketitle


    % ===TABLE OF CONTENTS===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \tableofcontents
        \newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic} % ===MAINMATTER===


    % Body 1
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \section{<Раздел>}

        \indent
        Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю...


\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Edit: I do load `\fontenc` first, it is just the code here, when I had typed it, I declared fontenc second, then copied and pasted it, then changed it and never updated this, sorry.

Comment: Can you condense this down to a minimal example? It doesn't matter that you want to use it in the title.

Comment: Please forgive me if I sound harsh, but it is literally in the third paragraph, above my first code block.

The issue is, when I try to write my name, `\author{Mat{\th}ew}` it does not work, because it assumes, rightly so, that I want the author to use T2A encoding. So, I need to declare that just that is English, then use the `\maketitle` command, but everything I try returns an error. `\otherlanguage{}{}`, `\begin{}`, `\foreignlanguage{}`, etc.

Thank you for the reply though, hopefully you can help.

Comment: Use `{\selectlanguage{english}Mat{\th}ew T. Scarbrough}%`.

Comment: @Cicada Yeah, for some reason, that won't work either? `! Argument of \bbl@iniline has an extra }.    <inserted text>    \par`

Which makes no sense.

Comment: The log message indicates there are an odd number of braces instead of an even number. Check that all the `{` have a matching `}`.

Comment: @Cicada I know that, except, that isn't the issue. I have tried `\author{\select...{eng}{name}}` and `\author{{\sel...{e}name}}` and `\auth{\sel{en}name}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting issue.

First of all, as has been pointed out in the comments by [Cicada](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/182648/cicada), you will want to change the language for your `\author`, since it is in English. If the language is correctly switched, the encoding will also be switched allowing you to use `\th` (or even `þ` - at least in modern versions of LaTeX) without problems.

The problem is that the naive approach of

```
\author{%
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{%
    Typeset by:\\
    Matþew Scarbrough}}
```

does not work as expected.

To understand why, we need to dig a little deeper in the macros that `article` uses to typeset the title.

You probably know that `\author` is defined (in `latex.ltx`) as

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\author[1]{\gdef\@author{#1}}
```

so `\author{<author>}` just saves `<author>` in the internal macro `\@author`. So far so good. With your settings (the default `notitlepage`) `\maketitle` does some preparation and then calls `\@maketitle` to do the typesetting of the title. `\@maketitle` is defined (in `article.cls`) as

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

This means that the author (as given in `\@author`) is typeset in a tabular environment.

In particular

```
\author{%
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{%
    Typeset by:\\
    Matþew Scarbrough}}
```

Will cause LaTeX to typeset

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{%
    Typeset by:\\
    Matþew Scarbrough}
\end{tabular}
```

Or arranged more suggestively

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Typeset by:\\
  Matþew Scarbrough}
\end{tabular}
```

Indeed, the `\\` starts a new row in the tabular environment and not 'just' a new line as one might have expected. Since each cell is in a group of its own, this causes issues with missing closing and opening braces. You can verify that a command in the first 'row' does not affect the second row with

```
\author{%
  \color{red}This is red\\
  This isn't red
}
```

Furthermore, everything works absolutely fine if you drop the `\\`

```
\author{%
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Typeset by: Matþew Scarbrough}%
}
```

A simple solution then is to issue `\foreignlanguage` for each 'row' separately in `\author`.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish,main=russian]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\addto\captionsUSenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}%
}

\title{%
  Учимся говорить по-алтайски.\\
  Урок № 1. Алфавит.%
}

\author{%
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Typeset by:}\\
  \foreignlanguage{USenglish}{Matþew Scarbrough}%
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{<Раздел>}
Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю...
\end{document}
```

[image: Typeset by: Matþew Scarbrough]

Comment: Oh my, thank you so much! I didn't know that about `\author{}` being tabular, but I suspected something was aloof! for when I had called `\selectlanguage{}` on one row, it would work, but then I couldn't get it to work for some reason.

I really need to learn about how TeX works itself and study some of the LaTeX macros—I am dumbfounded at what people do with it!

Comment: The code used here is only different from mine in one little (insignificant) detail: @moewe uses `\foreignlanguage` instead of `\selectlanguage` as I did. The outcome is identical. I'll admit, of course, that the explanation is spot on and well deserving of an accepted answer.

Comment: @phil-elkabat Your answer was good, but I didn't notice how you were calling `\selectlanguage`. I thought you were just saying to put `\fontenc` before `babel`, which makes no difference, to my understanding, in this context. It can, and I have seen `\fontenc` need to be called first, though

Comment: @phil-elkabat Understandable, sorry, I didn't see that you had added `\selectlanguage` until you mentioned it. But, I can say, and I think you might agree, that I am happy I didn't see, because otherwise I wouldn't have understood needing to declare, `\selectlanguage` or whatever other command on both lines. I even tried declaring `\foreignlanguage{}{}` to wrap around both arguments.

Comment: @MatþewScarbrough, I agree entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This compiles without error, if you load `fontenc` *before* `babel`:

```
% pdflatex

\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

    % ===MAIN PACKAGES===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

%%%     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % DEPROCATED IN NEWEST VERSIONS       %

        \usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}

%%%     \usepackage[pass]{geometry} % ALLOWS DECLARATION OF PAPER SIZE... %
                                    % IN SOME INSTANCES, WHERE NEEDED     %

        \usepackage[USenglish,main=russian]{babel}

            \addto\captionsUSenglish{%
                \renewcommand{\contentsname}%
                {Table of Contents}%
            }

        \usepackage{indentfirst}

    % ===SECONDARY PACKAGES===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \usepackage{xcolor}     % HIGHLIGHTING COLOURS

        \usepackage{soul}       % HIGHLIGHTING AND BETTER UNDERLINING 


    % ===TITLE===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \title{%
            Учимся говорить по-алтайски.    \\%
            %
            Урок № 1. Алфавит.%
        }


        \author{%
            ~Typeset by:    \\%
            %
            \selectlanguage{USenglish}Mat{\th}ew T. Scarbrough%
        }

        \date{\today}
        
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman} % ===FRONTMATTER===


    % ===TITLE===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \maketitle


    % ===TABLE OF CONTENTS===
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \tableofcontents
        \newpage


\pagenumbering{arabic} % ===MAINMATTER===


    % Body 1
    % - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

        \section{<Раздел>}

        \indent
        Съешь же ещё этих мягких французских булок да выпей чаю...


\end{document}
```

[image: thorn]

Comment: I am afraid to say it doesn't—this is hurting my head. I do load fontenc before babel, I will amend my post, because in it, fantenc is loaded before babel. I just don't understand. I have even tried deleting *.aux, *.log, *.toc, and *.aux, it is weird.

Comment: @MatþewScarbrough, I've successfully compiled my example on TeXLive 2020, 2019, and 2018. It took a while since a couple of fonts first had to be generated. Other than that no errors (not even warnings) whatsoever.